# How would I assign a JPA Entity to a set of "rotated" tables in database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

In my db, there is an entity that exists that has it's records partitioned in various tables named using this convention "Foo_MMYYYY"

For example, say I have a table to have log records of a users interaction on a website. Since these interactions happen very frequently and each time we store the interaction log in the db, a solution for this website is to have the Log entity partitioned with a set of "rotated" tables in our db. So every month, a new table is created (for Ex, for this month the table would be named `logs_042023`) that will contain that months set of log records.

Is there a way to dynamically set the table for a JPA entity by sending in  portion of the table name as an argument?

I tried looking up JPA documentation to see if there was a way to do this to no avail. It seems that the table name cannot be dynamically altered during runtime. What other options do I have?